# Paypal /Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData fails randomly with "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect."

Tags: paypal, paypal-permissions

I'm using paypal permissions api to authenticate user through paypal and get some permissions.

The problem is that sometimes the `/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData` call returns "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." even though I got the token and secret from a successful call to `/Permissions/GetAccessToken`

The weird thing though is that it is very unpredictable. It is sometimes fails and sometimes work with the sandbox, always fails on production (live paypal).

When it works it seems to work every time, when it fails it starts failing every time, that is until it changes.

Comment: Could it be related to browser cookies? Does it happen even after you clear all your browsing history and cookies?

Comment: it happens in an API call, not in browser. I'm doing it from console.

Comment: In that case looks like it could very well be an issue with your ISP (just guessing)... Best would be to try from another network when this happens; for example when you face the issue again, try making the API call from AWS or something... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal is doing some custom encoding and string manipulations while generating OAuth signature, for example, it will encode `.` to `%2E` first and it will be later on converted to lowercase string `%2e`.

If you are writing your own Paypal OAuth signature generation function and you missed some the the steps, your signature will be invalid. The "random" thing that you described is probably because those special characters are not guaranteed to show up in `token`/`token secret`. When they are not there, it will success and vice versa.

I made it work by translating bit-to-bit from Paypal's official Ruby SDK. (https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/lib/paypal-sdk/core/util/oauth_signature.rb)